# can not set "spark" as service account name when run spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running this command in my mac terminal,want to submit my test spark job on to one of our k8s cluster:

```
ID_TOKEN=`kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.users[0].user.auth-provider.config.id-token}'`

./bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://c2.us-south.containers.cloud.ibm.com:30326 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name Hello \
    --class scala.example.Hello \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=isap \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=default-us-icr-io \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.icr.io/cedp-isap/spark-for-apps:2.4.1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.caCertFile=/usr/local/opt/spark/ca.crt \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken=$ID_TOKEN \
    local:///opt/spark/jars/interimetl_2.11-1.0.jar
```

And I already created service account "spark", as well as cluster role binding yaml like this:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: isap
  name: pod-mgr
rules:
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io", ""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "delete"]
```

and

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-mgr-spark
  namespace: isap
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: spark
  namespace: isap
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-mgr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

But when I run above spark-submit command, I found the the log like this:

```
20/06/15 02:45:02 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: State changed, new state: 
 pod name: hello-1592203500709-driver
 namespace: isap
 labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-0c7f50ab2d21427aac9cf2381cb4bb64, spark-role -> driver
 pod uid: 375674d2-784a-4b32-980d-953488c8a8b2
 creation time: 2020-06-15T06:45:02Z
 service account name: default
 volumes: kubernetes-credentials, spark-local-dir-1, spark-conf-volume, default-token-p8pgf
 node name: N/A
 start time: N/A
 container images: N/A
 phase: Pending
 status: []
```

You will notice it is still using service account "default", rather than "Spark"
And the executor pod can not be created in my k8s cluster. Also no logs is displayed in created driver pod.

Could anyone can help to take a look what I missed here?Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#rbac) you need to use the service account `spark` as a parameter to spark submit

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. as you see, I am using "spark", but the log show the service account is always "default"

Comment: What was namespace where you created the service account? Was it in isap namespace?

Comment: Yes, if you are looking above cluster role and cluster role binding yaml, spark is created fir namespace "isap"

Comment: Please add service account creation command or yaml in the question

Comment: for "spark" service account creation, just using "kubectl create serviceaccount spark", and then run above clusterrole binding yaml.

Comment: Okay can you share output of kubectl get sa -n isap

Comment: Nicks-MacBook-Pro:spark nick$ kubectl get sa -n isap 
NAME                      SECRETS   AGE
default                   1         11d
quiet-emu-spark           1         3d20h
quiet-emu-sparkoperator   1         3d20h
spark                     1         10d

Comment: I add a new answer, hope it still help

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you already figure it out the issue. Hope my input is still useful.

There are two places which whill check against RBAC.

First, when you execute the spark-submit, it will call k8s web api to create the driver pod. Later the driver pod will call k8s api to create executor pod.

I saw you already create the spark service account , role and rolebinding. You also use them for your driver pod. That is fine, but the problem, you haven't assign the user when creating the driver pod. So K8S believes you are still using "system:anonymous".

You can also assign the "spark" sa to it by config "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.*", one example I put here

```
   spark-submit ^
   --master k8s://xxx ^
   --name chen-pi ^
   --deploy-mode cluster ^
   --driver-memory 8g ^
   --executor-memory 16g ^
   --executor-cores 2  ^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark-py:v3.1.1 ^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/opt/spark ^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile=./local/ca.crt   ^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.oauthTokenFile=./local/token   ^
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=./local/token   ^
   ./spark-examples/python/skeleton/skeleton.py
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, error msg is like

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager$1.onFailure(WatchConnectionManager.java:198) : Exec Failure: HTTP 403, Status: 403 - pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:{pod namespace}:default" cannot watch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "{driver pod namespace}"
```

string in {} means your namespace.

the problem was always using default service account unless I have ClusterRoleBinding and Service Account like your 'spark'.

I also tried `--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark` but it never works.

Now, I solved it by setting **Application Pod's service account.**

If you use Deployment, it can be set in yaml like `spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName: spark`

It is Pod spec, so in `kind: Pod`, you can set it like `spec.serviceAccountName: spark`

I'm using client mode so a little difference may appear, but maybe have similar solution.

hope someone get helped.